# How to load data with numpy with no fixed column size

Tags: python, arrays, text, numpy

How can we load a text file with tab delimited values but with no fixed column size in the way that the missing values are skipped completely ending up with a list/array or whatever container containing numpy arrays for each line (or a whole numpy array? -> might be impossible, because numpy needs fixed sizes)?

Is this only possible by reading in each line with python and then converting with `loadtxt` the line into a 1D array?

```
list=[]
for lineString in file:
    list.append( np.loadtxt(lineString) )
```

or is it possible somehow with load txt?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

If your file looks like this:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2
8.0 9   97  54
```

Then doing this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('yourfile.txt',sep='\t')
```

gives:

```
   1  2   3   4   5   6
0  1  2 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  8  9  97  54 NaN NaN
```

To convert to a numpy array:

```
np.array(pd.read_csv('yourfile.txt',sep='\t'))


array([[  1.,   2.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  8.,   9.,  97.,  54.,  nan,  nan]])
```