# read an ascii file into a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an `ascii` file and I want to read it into a `numpy array`. But it was failing and for the first number in the file, it returns 'NaN' when I use `numpy.genfromtxt`. Then I tried to use the following way of reading the file into an array:

```
lines = file('myfile.asc').readlines()
X     = []
for line in lines:
    s = str.split(line)
    X.append([float(s[i]) for i in range(len(s))])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 15.514
```

when I printed the first line of the file it looks like :

```
>>> s
['\xef\xbb\xbf15.514', '15.433', '15.224', '14.998', '14.792', '15.564', '15.386', '15.293', '15.305', '15.132', '15.073', '15.005', '14.929', '14.823', '14.766', '14.768', '14.789']
```

how could I read such a file into a `numpy array` without problem and any presumption about the number of rows and columns?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22196962/1461850

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is encoded with utf-8 with BOM. Use [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) with [`utf-8-sig`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) encoding to handle it correctly (To exclude BOM `\xef\xbb\xbf`).

```
import codecs

X = []
with codecs.open('myfile.asc', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    for line in f:
        s = line.split()
        X.append([float(s[i]) for i in range(len(s))])
```

**UPDATE** You don't need to use index at all:

```
with codecs.open('myfile.asc', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    X = [[float(x) for x in line.split()] for line in f]
```

BTW, instead of using the unbound method `str.split(line)`, use `line.split()` if you have no special reason to do it.

Comment: what is the difference of using `str.split(line)` and `line.split()`?

Answer (score 7):

Based on @falsetru's answer, I want to provide a solution with Numpy's file reading capabilities:

```
import numpy as np
import codecs

with codecs.open('myfile.asc', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    X = np.loadtxt(f)
```

It loads the file into an open file instance using the correct encoding. Numpy uses this kind of handle (it can also use handles from `open()` and works seemless like in every other case.